# iPhone app using facebook connect login to authenticate with web server possible?

Tags: iphone, web-services, authentication, facebook

I'm developing an iPhone app that will need a login system in order for users to post content to a server. I'd really like to use facebook connect for this as it's a very community driven app. Is it possible for me to securely authenticate with the web server without the user having to create a username and password specifically for my app?

One idea I've had is using my app's FBConnect secret key as a password for an HTTPS connection? The app would be able to tell if a user is logged in, and only connect to the server if so. This would also stop any other connections from hackers etc I assume?

Answer (score 0):

Although not just restricted to Facebook, Janrain provide a great solution to login from various openid methods including facebook connect. I believe there is a free product for non-commercial use. There is a demo iPhone app on the app store to show you how it works etc.

http://www.janrain.com/products/engage

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use the [Facebook iOS SDK](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk)?

Comment: thanks, but I don't think this does what I want alone. I need something else with it.