# IPhone Facebook Connect then Login to ASP.NET MVC Server

Tags: iphone, asp.net-mvc, facebook

I have Facebook Connect Implemented on the IPhone
I have a ASP.NET MVC "API" site that I want the IPhone client to connect and login to.
This enable me to then connect the facebook user to the internal asp.net memberbership provider.

How would I connect the two end points?

I am not sure a secure way to authenticate the user after they have successfully logged in via the IPhone. The parameters that usually provided by the Facebook Cookie like sig_request..etc... is not available on the IPhone.

Similar to which was never answered: [iPhone app using facebook connect login to authenticate with web server possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4276395/iphone-app-using-facebook-connect-login-to-authenticate-with-web-server-possible)